# Filter [ME] is not working after migration from Domain A to Domain B. Working for user with entry in Only Domain B

Tags: filter, task-list, domain, token

I am the primary site collection administrator on my SharePoint 2013 environment.  I have a task list with a filter view: "assigned to = [me]".
My own tasks show fine when I am logged in.  However others in my team do not see their own task(no items displayed on their computer and when I asked them to login from my computer).
I though it was a permission issue, however one of my team members is the secondary site collection administrator.

Some details below:

-The organisation recently migrated from Domain A to Domain B. Existing users have profile in both domains.  I just started 2 weeks ago and I only have profile in domain B.
-When I click on my name in the "Assigned to" field it displays my profile page with the URL: http://domain B/my/person.aspx?accountname=####
The account format displayed on the page is: domain B\username

-When I click on my other team members their profile page has the following URL format: http://domain B/sites/portal/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=#
The account format displayed on the page is: i:0#.w|domain A\username

-I have May 2015 CU applied so a solution(google searched) to apply March 2015 CU does not solve my issue.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: The reason why my team members tasks do not display is because they were selecting their names from the auto-complete lookup in person/group field.  The auto-complete was pulling their profile from AD were from the old domain A.  If I manually entered their new domain and username manually, the tasks will display afterwards.  Ex: "domian B\username".  
However, now my question is how do I configure the auto-complete to source to just the new domain and not the old one?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run [Move-SPuser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - so the user permissions are correctly migrated to new domain.

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\JaneDoe" -NewAlias "Domain\JaneSmith"
```